# SOGO: No child available to handle incoming request / pid xxx has been hanging in the same request for x minutes

Tags: activesync

I am trying to add SOGo to an already working server with Postfix + Dovecot.

The server is Centos 7, 2 core with 3Gb RAM with less than 10 users. Sogo installed from official repo: sogo-2.3.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64

/etc/sysconfig/sogo is set up for 10 workers: PREFORK=10"

Sogo is configured with 10 workers with this configuration:

```
    WOListenQueueSize=10;
    WOWatchDogRequestTimeout=60;

    SOGoMaximumPingInterval = 354;
    SOGoMaximumSyncInterval = 354;

    SOGoInternalSyncInterval = 15;
    SOGoMaximumSyncWindowSize = 50;
    SOGoMaximumSyncResponseSize = 2048;
```

The problem seems to be whith activesync clients (ms outlook). SOGo processes starts eating all the RAM and sometimes hangs (process can't be killed with signal 15). The problem seems to be related to The log file reports:

```
    Feb 19 13:30:26 sogod [13164]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:30:26 sogod [13163]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:30:26 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:30:26 sogod [13155]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:30:27 sogod [13152]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:30:27 sogod [13150]: [WARN]  pid 13168 has been hanging in the same request for 3 minutes
    Feb 19 13:30:28 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:30:28 sogod [13150]: [WARN]  pid 13164 has been hanging in the same request for 3 minutes
    Feb 19 13:30:29 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:30:29 sogod [13150]: [WARN]  pid 13163 has been hanging in the same request for 2 minutes
    Feb 19 13:30:30 sogod [13168]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:30:30 sogod [13150]: [WARN]  pid 13151 has been hanging in the same request for 1 minutes

    Feb 19 13:35:03 sogod [13150]: [WARN]  pid 13153 has been hanging in the same request for 5 minutes
    Feb 19 13:35:04 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:35:06 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:35:07 sogod [13153]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
    Feb 19 13:35:07 sogod [13150]: [ERROR]  No child available to handle incoming request!
    Feb 19 13:35:08 sogod [13164]:  Sleeping 15 seconds while detecting changes in Ping...
```

I used gdb to get a trace of one of the hanging processes. The response is this:

```
    #0 0x00007f176ddcc49d in nanosleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #1 0x00007f176ddcc334 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #2 0x00007f17608e8a99 in -[SOGoActiveSyncDispatcher processPing:inResponse:] () from /usr/lib64/GNUstep/SOGo/ActiveSync.SOGo/./ActiveSync
    #3 0x00007f17608eee4b in -[SOGoActiveSyncDispatcher dispatchRequest:inResponse:context:] () from /usr/lib64/GNUstep/SOGo/ActiveSync.SOGo/./ActiveSync
    #4 0x00007f1760d50d84 in -[SOGoMicrosoftActiveSyncActions microsoftServerActiveSyncAction] () from /usr/lib64/GNUstep/SOGo/MainUI.SOGo/./MainUI
    #5 0x00007f1773e61113 in -[WODirectAction performActionNamed:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #6 0x00007f1773ee3834 in -[SoActionInvocation callOnObject:withPositionalParametersWhenNotNil:inContext:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #7 0x00007f1773edee98 in -[SoObjectMethodDispatcher dispatchInContext:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #8 0x00007f1773ee0f09 in -[SoObjectRequestHandler handleRequest:inContext:session:application:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #9 0x00007f1773e72753 in -[WORequestHandler handleRequest:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #10 0x00007f1773e3433c in -[WOCoreApplication dispatchRequest:usingHandler:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #11 0x00007f1773e3463f in -[WOCoreApplication dispatchRequest:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #12 0x00007f17751fbb4d in -[SOGo dispatchRequest:] ()
    #13 0x00007f1773ed1a85 in -[WOHttpTransaction _run] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #14 0x00007f1773ed1de5 in -[WOHttpTransaction run] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #15 0x00007f1773ecd9e4 in -[WOHttpAdaptor runConnection:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #16 0x00007f1773ecdc02 in -[WOHttpAdaptor _handleAcceptedConnection:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #17 0x00007f1773ecdff7 in -[WOHttpAdaptor _handleConnection:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #18 0x00007f1773ece2c3 in -[WOHttpAdaptor acceptControlMessage:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #19 0x00007f177261613f in -[NSNotificationCenter _postAndRelease:] () from /lib64/libgnustep-base.so.1.24
    #20 0x00007f17732a0e3d in -[NSObject(FileObjectWatcher) receivedEvent:type:extra:forMode:] () from /lib64/libNGExtensions.so.4.9
    #21 0x00007f177271ceea in -[GSRunLoopCtxt pollUntil:within:] () from /lib64/libgnustep-base.so.1.24
    #22 0x00007f177265d870 in -[NSRunLoop acceptInputForMode:beforeDate:] () from /lib64/libgnustep-base.so.1.24
    #23 0x00007f177265dd22 in -[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:] () from /lib64/libgnustep-base.so.1.24
    #24 0x00007f1773e33b94 in -[WOCoreApplication run] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #25 0x00007f17751fb1fe in -[SOGo run] ()
    #26 0x00007f1773e7bc5e in -[WOWatchDog _runChildWithControlSocket:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #27 0x00007f1773e7c0f1 in -[WOWatchDog _spawnChild:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #28 0x00007f1773e7c7d9 in -[WOWatchDog _ensureChildren] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #29 0x00007f1773e7d7f6 in -[WOWatchDog run:argc:argv:] () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #30 0x00007f1773e7df21 in WOWatchDogApplicationMain () from /lib64/libNGObjWeb.so.4.9
    #31 0x00007f17751fa491 in main ()
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

**vim /etc/sysconfig/sogo**

> PREFORK=10
> USER=sogo

**vim /etc/rc.d/init.d/sogod**

> PREFORK=10